# Can't get the selected radio button value via JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form id="pick-status-form">
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='ststusesList' value='1' class='statuses-list'>1</label></div>
    <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='ststusesList' value='2' class='statuses-list'>2</label></div>
    <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='ststusesList' value='3' class='statuses-list'>3</label></div>
    <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='ststusesList' value='4' class='statuses-list'>4</label></div>
    </div></form>
```

And these Jquery code:

```
$("button#submit").click(function () {
      var form = $('#pick-status-form');
      var selectedStatusID = form.find('input[name=ststusesList]:checked').val();
      alert(selectedStatusID);
});
```

The problem is that the value of `selectedStatusID` is always undefined.

My question is why and how can I fix it?

**HERE is a fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/b6xFA/

Comment: Where is that code? is it in an handler?

Comment: I updated my question, pleas review it

Comment: @NaveTseva where is button code ? and is this generated dynamically ?

Comment: There is no button in your html.

Comment: @NaveTseva Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @HenkJansen the button is outside the form tag, I don't think it's metter where to put it.

Comment: @NaveTseva http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/K4Sbu/ What is wrong with that?

Comment: @NaveTseva Also, do you have more than 1 `<form id="pick-status-form">`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon No, I have not

Comment: Your code works just fine directly executed (not inside the button click callback). Could be you submit the form and that's why it is undefined. Try to use `function(e)` and `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6xFA/

Comment: @NaveTseva thank! When jQuery is loaded, it work : http://jsfiddle.net/b6xFA/1/. Your problem is somewhere else....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just works as intended.

**Why does it gives undefined?**

This is because *the value of a checkbox is only declared when it is checked*.
*None of your checkboxes are checked* when running the page for the first time.

See this example were the first checkbox is checked by default:

```
<input type='radio' name='ststusesList' value='1' class='statuses-list' checked="checked" />
```

### [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PjvPW/)

Comment: But after I click submit there is one checked checkbox and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Well then it is something beyond the code you submitted. Could you provide more code? Because even with a button it does work [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PjvPW/2/)